# How to delete the message users have reacted to

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Trying to delete the original user command the bot reply after the bot is reacted to. For some reason, it only works every other time and when it does work it relays a `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message` error

```js
const isValidCommand = (message, cmdName) => message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(PREFIX + cmdName)
client.on('message', function(message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (isValidCommand(message, "banker"))
    message.reply("Bankers are on the way to get your cash. Please be patient as Bankers are busy individuals as well. If there is a major delay you are welcome to use !HeadBanker.      Bankers Please React With Money Bag When Sent/Sending!").then(r_msg =>
      r_msg.react(''))
  if (isValidCommand(message, "banker"))
    message.channel.send("<@&717082379470110885> Banker Cash Needed")
    .then(msg => {
      msg.delete({
        timeout: 0100
      })
    })
  if (isValidCommand(message, "headbanker"))
    message.reply("I see you have pinged Head Banker. If its between 14:00TCT and 5:00TCT you should get a response within a minute or two max. If no response in five minutes you have permission to ping again.").then(r_msg =>
      r_msg.react(''))
  if (isValidCommand(message, "headbanker"))
    message.channel.send("<@&716843712092569640> Cash Needed")
    .then(msg => {
      msg.delete({
          timeout: 0100
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    })

  client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    let limit = 2;
    if (reaction.emoji.name == '' && reaction.count >= limit) reaction.message.delete()
      .catch(console.log);
    if (reaction.emoji.name == '' && reaction.count >= limit) message.delete()
      .catch(console.log);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's caused by the fact that you've declared your `messageReactionAdd` listener **inside** your `message` listener: that means that **every time** you get a new message your client will add a new handler, and so it will try to delete the same message multiple time, resulting in an "unknown message" error from the API.
Instead of adding a listener for the reactions on your client, you should try creating a reaction collector using either [`Message.awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) or [`Message.createReactionCollector()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector). Here's an example:

```js
const isValidCommand = (message, cmdName) => message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(PREFIX + cmdName)

client.on('message', function(message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (isValidCommand(message, "banker")) { // Use single if statements where possible
    message.reply("Bankers are on the way to get your cash. Please be patient as Bankers are busy individuals as well. If there is a major delay you are welcome to use !HeadBanker.      Bankers Please React With Money Bag When Sent/Sending!").then(r_msg =>
      r_msg.react(''))
    message.channel.send("<@&717082379470110885> Banker Cash Needed")
      .then(msg => {
        msg.delete({ timeout: 0100 })
      })
  }
  if (isValidCommand(message, "headbanker")) {
    message.reply("I see you have pinged Head Banker. If its between 14:00TCT and 5:00TCT you should get a response within a minute or two max. If no response in five minutes you have permission to ping again.").then(r_msg =>
      r_msg.react(''))
    message.channel.send("<@&716843712092569640> Cash Needed")
      .then(msg => {
        msg.delete({ timeout: 0100 })
          .catch(console.log);
      })
  }

  message.awaitReactions(r => r.emoji.name == '', { max: 2 }).then(collected => {
    if (collected.size >= 2)
      message.delete()
  })
})
```

Also, it's good practice not to repeat `if` statements, you should merge them wherever you can.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something when I changed over to something closer to your example but now it's not deleting any of the messages after a user reacts to the bot reply. Any reason messages wouldn't be deleted with the example you gave?

Comment: The bot will delete the message with the command after two users react to it with that emoji, because that's what you seemed to want to do with the code (you didn't include the desired behavior...). I'll update my answer, but first I need to know what do you want it do

Comment: I actually managed to figure out what I was doing wrong is fixed it. If you don't mind I was wondering if you knew of a way for the reaction delete to only work if it was the original author of the message and/or someone with a specific role.

Comment: You can edit the filter function (which now only checks for the emoji) to include a check for the user (which is passed as the second argument to the filter function). Regarding the role check, you'll need to use the user parameter from the filter to fetch the member from the guild you get from `message.guild`; once you have the GuildMember object you can then check if it has any role